# Ark of the Covenant on Ryloth?

Tags: star-wars, indiana-jones, et-the-extra-terrestrial, ark-of-the-covenant

In Star Wars: The Clone Wars, in S1E21 : Liberty on Ryloth, there is a scene where it appears the droids are loading the Ark of the Covenant onto a ship as the pillage the planet while they evacuate.  This appears to be a Lucasfilm nod to the Indiana Jones series.  Lucasfilm and ILM are pretty famous for their special effects Easter eggs. We also know that ET and the Star Wars universes are hinted at being tied together and the beings from ET have visited Earth.

See the stretch I'm making here?  Following that logic, are there any stories that show the Ark of the Covenant being of extra-terrestrial origin (i.e. that is has traveled from Ryloth, eventually ending up on Earth)?

As a non-lore aside, are there other examples of the Ark of the Covenant specifically that Lucasfilm/ILM have snuck into other projects?

[image: Ark of the Covenant on Ryloth]

Comment: You mean, just like _Club Obi Wan_ in _Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom_?

Comment: It's an easter egg. Any attempt to tie it into the Canon is going to be pointless

Comment: @Richard ...but given how Star Wars canon works, that's sure as hell not going to stop someone somewhere from *trying*...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Indiana Jones visits the Well of Souls in order to find the Lost Ark, C3PO and R2D2 are visible in a carving.

[image]

If you want to read this as a connection you're free to, but there's no evidence I'm aware of to support such a reading.

Comment: There's also this (non-canonical) Star Wars/Indiana Jones crossover comic from Dark Horse: http://io9.com/5805510/the-lost-indiana-jones-star-wars-crossover-was-really-depressing