# Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom: deliberate Star Wars connection?

Tags: star-wars, george-lucas, indiana-jones

Near the start of the film *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom*, I've just noticed that the club they leave is called the Obi-Wan Club. Presumably, George Lucas, put this reference in as a joke. Are there any other instances in his films where Star War references are made?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60704/ark-of-the-covenant-on-ryloth/60709#60709

Comment: https://gizmodo.com/the-hidden-easter-eggs-which-link-star-wars-and-indian-1446924666

Comment: This is gonna be a big endless list that keeps growing as films continue to make references, I've therefore edited to be _only_ George Lucas films, as once he's dead that's the end of the possible list, gucci?

Comment: @Edlothiad that's reasonable

Comment: These references, of course, lead to the theory that all of Indiana Jones, and therefore our entire reality (as it is concretely set in our history) is merely [Han Solo's carbonite fever dream](http://www.indianajonesminute.com/han-solos-dream/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Raiders of the Lost Ark:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Please state how these are references.

Comment: I'm not sure whether OB-CPO is a reference of not.

Comment: OB is the country code for Peru, but they have airplane registrations in the form OB-1234. CPO can refer to C3PO. In the middle of the circle, you can see a crude drawing of R2D2 (above the eye symbol).

Comment: Plus, the B makes it look like it says 3-CPO

Comment: Having the plane's tail number be OB-001 was just too on the nose, I guess?

Answer (score 8):

Along with the Club Obi Wan reference in *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom*, there is a much more subtle appearance of the *Star Wars* droids in an Egyptian mural in *Raiders of the Lost Ark*  The references are [described here](http://mentalfloss.com/article/55697/r2-d2-and-c-3po-briefly-appear-raiders-lost-ark).

[image: Droids]

The article also points out that the number 1138 (and sometimes the full "THX 1138") comes up many, many times in Lucas's work.  However the article identifies these as references  to Lucas's first film, which is not quite correct.  Even the title of *THX 1138* was a reference to one of the critical events of Lucas's life; that was the license plate number of the car that slammed into and flipped Lucas's car over when he was in high school in 1962.

Comment: Are those the only 3?

Comment: Those are the only ones in the Indiana Jones movies that I'm aware of.

Comment: The question extends it to all Lucas films, I have no idea if he's directed anything else, but a complete answer would really have a list of all of them, it might be that this is the complete list, I'm just inquiring.